# RSS Feed Question about lastBuildDate

Tags: rss

We use our RSS feed to create a daily email digest of daily posts. Posts are scheduled every evening to post early in the am the next day. We use a MailChimp RSS campaign to pull in the post data and send it to our email list every morning. All has been working very well for years. However, this week MailChimp first failed to send out a campaign and then today it picked up posts from the previous day, even though I see today's posts in the feed.

The only thing I'm seeing in the RSS feed that might be an issue is the lastBuildDate seems to be off. For instance right now as I look at the RSS feed XML (my local time is Fri Sept 29, 5:16 pm PST) it shows: Fri, 29 Sep 2023 05:23:14 +0000 which was 10:23 pm last night Pacific Time. The puDates for each item in the feed are correct e.g. Fri, 29 Sep 2023 09:35:00 +0000. It looks like the lastBuildDate isn't updating properly. That's the only thing I thought of that might cause MailChimp to pull in the wrong posts. But I have no idea how to fix it.

This has me puzzled. I tried refreshing permalinks.I've checked the server time settings, I checked and reset the timezone settings in WordPress (set to Los Angeles) and it is reporting the correct time in Site Health.The feed validates: https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.schwartzreport.net%2Ffeed%2F

What am I missing?

I have since found this WordPress 8 month old ticket https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/57661

I'm really hoping there is a fix for this. The lastBuildDate will update in the feed if as described in the ticket I edit a published post and save it without making changes. However, in my case, that means I need to do that after the posts are published around 2 a.m. and before the MailChimp campaign triggers at 4 a.m. PT. Not very conducive to sleep for me.